# Quotes in image alt break HTML

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, alt-text

While creating a question, I used quotes in an images alt text. It rendered correctly. To be sure that nothing was wrong, I opened up Chrome's Inspector on the rendered output. Sure enough, the quotes were embedded *directly* in the alt text which would break HTML validation:

[image: Screenshot]

If you look, you can see the `alt` text reading `alt="Exhibit A: "VES2 Bassdrum 001" WAV"` which is *obviously* an error. Can we fix this to escape quotes in the `alt` text?

For reference, the quote character (`"`) is `U+0022` ([QUOTATION MARK](http://codepoints.net/U+0022)), which is escapable with `&#x0022;`, `&#34;`, or the simple `&quot;`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about anything related to the Stack Exchange network, but rather confusion about a browser's code inspector tool.

Comment: @animuson This question is asking about HTML renderings of StackExchange's markdown.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi: No it's not; not at all. Please see the answer which explains that this is not even an issue at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they were asking about the HTML rendering of Markdown, even though the answer pertains only to their web inspector, but that could just be me.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi: They're claiming something on the SE network is a bug based on something that's not related to the SE network at all. In the previous system, you'd know it as "too localized."

Comment: Hrm... I guess I'm getting confused by "off topic" being the catch all for the edge case questions. Makes sense, though.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi you are correct.

Comment: @animuson How was I supposed to know Chrome's inspector did that? That's what this question was about. I thought that the markdown renderer wasn't escaping quotes. Hence the [meta-tag:bug] tag...

Comment: @ColeJohnson: That doesn't make it on-topic for Meta. The underlying issue has *absolutely nothing* to do with Stack Exchange, and it caused you to report a bug that doesn't actually exist. Meta is not the place to learn how to use your developer tools.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because even though it is about an issue reproduced using an SE site, the core problem isn't our fault.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The web inspector is misleading you. It displays the non-encoded value there so that it's more friendly to edit in-place. If you viewed the source of that page after saving, or checked the value of `innerHTML` on the parent element, you should see that it actually is escaped.

Take a look at the source of the image below in this post for an example.

[image: I have a "quote" in here]

> [image]

Good thing, too, otherwise this would be an XSS vulnerability.